# We are given a 15 bit string which must contain exactly 9 0's and 6 1's. Every 1 to be followed by a 0. # of possibilities to place the remaining 0s?

Tags: combinatorics

We are given a 15 bit string which must contain exactly 9 0's and 6 1's. Every 1 to be followed by a 0. # of possibilities to place the remaining 0s?

I believe the answer is (3+7-1) choose 3 as I set this problem up as a stars & bars problem. However, I am having trouble decerning why that answer is correct and (7C3 + 7C2 + 7C1) would be incorrect. The logic for the latter answer being:

```
first possibility, the last 3 zeros are separated => 7C3 second possibility, the three   
zeros are all in the same place => 7 ...
```

Could anyone offer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the simplest way to answer it is to see tre problem as «we have a 9-chunk string made of six "10" and three "0"», and indeed you come out with $ 9\choose{3}$.

In your other formulation, I think you forgot that the "remaining" zeros are indistinguishable from the one you attached to each 1.

Comment: Thank you mau my lord and savior >3